# C++ Optional Reference

Tags: c++, c++17, optional, reference

Here is a good [article](https://foonathan.net/2018/07/optional-reference/) on an optional reference type in C++. They discuss `std::optional<T&>`, but as that doesn't compile I have made my own.

One purpose of this type is to remove raw pointers from function signatures (where references alone cannot be used), as a raw pointer does not convey any indication of what it will be used for (become owned, deleted, iterated, dereferenced, etc).

```
#include <functional>
#include <optional>

template<typename T>
/** @brief An optional refference **/
class opt_ref {
    using std_opt_ref = std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<T>>;
    std_opt_ref data = std::nullopt;
public:
    using type = typename std::reference_wrapper<T>::type;

    /** public member functions **/

    T& get() { return data.value().get(); }
    const T& get() const { return data.value().get(); }
    bool has_value() const { return data.has_value(); }
    T& value_or(T&& other) const { return data.value_or(other); }

    /** constructors **/

    opt_ref() {}
    opt_ref(T& source) : data(source) {}
    opt_ref& operator = (T&& other) { data.value().get() = other; return *this; }

    /** comparisons **/

    bool operator == (const T& t) { return data.value() == t; }
    bool operator == (const std::nullopt_t&) {return !data.has_value(); }

    /** implicit conversion **/

    operator T&() { return data.value().get(); }
    operator const T&() const { return data.value().get(); }
    operator std::reference_wrapper<T>() { return data.value(); }
    operator const std::reference_wrapper<T>() const { return data.value(); }
};
```

Comment: A strange article indeed.

Comment: Here's another article for you: https://thephd.github.io/to-bind-and-loose-a-reference-optional  It seems like you've implemented assign-through? Is that what you meant to do?

Comment: Another nice article: [Why Optional References Didn’t Make It In C++17](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/10/05/pros-cons-optional-references/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Design

References are different from pointers in two ways:

- they are designed to be aliases to the objects they refer to, so syntactically they are treated with special care;
- they cannot be rebound.

You cannot always emulate the first bullet with an `optional` — for example, there's no general way to make `opt.f()` call `opt.value().f()`.  You still have to resort to some other syntax like `opt->value()`.  Therefore, my advice is to simply treat `opt_ref<T>` like an immutable nullable pointer that does not own the referred-to object — don't follow `std::reference_wrapper`.

## Code Review

> ```
> using type = typename std::reference_wrapper<T>::type;
> ```

[`typename std::reference_wrapper<T>::type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper#Member_types) is just `T`.  Also, the standard terminology is `value_type`.

> ```
> T& get() { return data.value().get(); }
> const T& get() const { return data.value().get(); }
> bool has_value() const { return data.has_value(); }
> T& value_or(T&& other) const { return data.value_or(other); }
> ```

`has_value` is `noexcept`.  Why does `value_or` take an rvalue reference?  To introduce dangling references as in `opt.value_or(1)`?  Take an lvalue reference instead.

> ```
> bool operator == (const T& t) { return data.value() == t; }
> bool operator == (const std::nullopt_t&) {return !data.has_value(); }
> ```

I'm not sure this is the right approach.  The first `==` compares values (and throws an exception if there is no value), whereas the second `==` compares the references themselves.  You can imitate the behavior of `std::optional`:

```
bool operator==(const opt_ref<T>& a, const opt_ref<T>& b)
{
    if (a.has_value() != b.has_value()) {
        return false;
    } else if (!a.has_value()) { // and !b.has_value()
        return true;
    } else {
        return a.get() == b.get();
    }
}
```

> ```
> operator T&() { return data.value().get(); }
> operator const T&() const { return data.value().get(); }
> operator std::reference_wrapper<T>() { return data.value(); }
> operator const std::reference_wrapper<T>() const { return data.value(); }
> ```

As I said before: are you sure you want this (especially the implicit conversions to `reference_wrapper`)?

## Other functionalities

Consider:

- `operator*` and `operator->`;
- `explicit operator bool`;
- `has_value`;
- ...